# Angular 7 How to trigger mat-error manually?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-validation

I have a a control which I want to validate:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Title " required [formControl]="titleFormControl">
    <mat-error *ngIf="titleFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Title is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="titleFormControl.hasError('duplicate')">
      Name already used
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and in the component I have something like

```
titleFormControl = new FormControl('', {
    validators: [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4)
    ],
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.titleFormControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(this.isNameDuplicate.bind(this))
  }

 isNameDuplicate(): void {
    const ret = this.data.findIndex((item, index) =>
      index !== this.selSheetIndex && item.id >= 0 && this.titleFormControl.value === item.title) >= 0;
    if (ret) {
      this.titleFormControl.setErrors({ 'duplicate': true });
      this.titleFormControl.markAsDirty(); // doesn't help neither :-/
    }
  }
```

If I change the text the `mat-error` is displayed immediately if the title is missing. When I change the content so `isNameDuplicate()` results in an error the control has an error `'duplicate'`

I would expect that `mat-error` is displayed immediately but somehow this is not true. The evaluation of `mat-error` (for `'duplicate'`) is only triggered if I change the focus, e.g. change into another field. (while `'required'` is displayed immediately)

Is there a way to trigger the evaluation manually so the `'duplicate'` error `mat-error` is displayed as well immediately?

Note: I know I could do it with an error matcher but frankly said I have no clue how to apply a check with a given list. Therefore I am looking for a solution for this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with  this (ValidatorFn):

```
titleFormControl = new FormControl('', {
validators: [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4),
  this.isNameDuplicate.bind(this) // <----- Custom validator method call
],
});


 isNameDuplicate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
 const ret = this.data.findIndex((item, index) => index !== this.selSheetIndex && item.id >= 0 && this.titleFormControl.value === item.title) >= 0;
 if (ret) {
  return { duplicate: true };
 }
}
```

in html

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="titleFormControl.hasError('duplicate')">
  Name already used
</mat-error>
```

Comment: Oh thx...since I have two similar answers and yours is with the correct (working) syntax I'll accept yours. Inspecting the issue more closely I recognize just now that even with your approach the very first validation hit is not displayed. If I change focus and than back it works. No further focus changes required. Seems like I need to first loose focus on this field before the later validations are properly displayed in the control. No idea about the why...

Answer (score 1):

Replace your validator in Async Validator of `formControl` and not in `ngOnInit`

```js
titleFormControl = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      this.isNameDuplicate.bind(this)
    ]
  );
```

```js
 isNameDuplicate: ValidatorFn = (control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    const ret = this.data.findIndex((item, index) =>
    index !== this.selSheetIndex && item.id >= 0 && control.value === item.title) >= 0;
    return ret ? {duplicate: true} : {};
  }
```

Comment: `isNameDuplicate` doesn't look as if it's doing anything async, it's just an array lookup.

Comment: So just replace the logic of `AsyncvalidatorFn` with `ValidatorFn` and just return the object in plain and not in Observable form

Comment: @Silente13: somehow the syntax has a problem. If I do it like you describe I get an error `- 'control' is declared but its value is never read.
- '=>' expected.`
And the second comment - I'm not sure what to do with it about replacing `AsyncvalidatorFn` with `ValidatorFn`. Does it mean your code is OK and that's just some background info?

Comment: @LeO I updated the answer with `ValidatorFn` and `control` is never read because the function was read the value from `FormControl` and not from binding. Fixed that!